# How to call Java from C++ using jni with C++ Builder

Tags: java, c++, c++builder

I'm currently working on a project, calling tika from C++. I am already blocked for calling java methods with C++ using jni with Embarcadero C++ Builder. I think that the jvm.dll provided by the JDK is *not* suitable for making a connection with Embarcadero (judging by `[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'JNI_CreateJavaVM' referenced from "path"`)

I've tried using IMPDEF and implib to generate jvm.lib, but while Embarcadero accepts it, it doesn't resolve the issue.

I think that, if you're using an IDE that uses COFF object files (Visual Studio), you wouldn't run into this issue (I haven't verified this, though).
I'm really stuck; how can I fix this?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>

int main() {
  JavaVM *jvm; /* denotes a Java VM */
  JNIEnv *env; /* pointer to native method interface */

  JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
  JavaVMOption options[1];
  options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:\\Users\\Documents\\RA   Studio\\Projects\\DJNI\\HelloWorld.java";
  vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
  vm_args.options = options;
  vm_args.nOptions = 1;
  vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

  /* Create the Java VM */
  int res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&env, &vm_args); // this is what it can't find

  /* invoke the Main.test method using the JNI */
  jclass cls = env->FindClass("HelloWorld");
  jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "staticInt", "(I)I");
  env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid,10);

  /* We are done. */
  jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: i included the path of jni.h, jni_md and jvm.dll,but can not create virtual machine,i have this error:
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'JNI_CreateJavaVM' referenced from C:\USERS\DOCUMENTS\RAD STUDIO\PROJECTS\CPPTOJAVA\WIN32\DEBUG\MAIN.OBJ

Comment: i think that jvm.dll of jdk it's not suitable to c++ builder !!!!!!

Comment: That error has nothing to do with jvm.dll.  It is a `linker` error, and DLL's are not involved in building or linking an application.  A DLL is only involved once your program is *running*.  More than likely, your `jvm.lib` that you made compatible with Embarcadero is not being included in your project.

Comment: I called it jvm2, i puted it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\lib and i did project>right clic>options>include path and i added this path witch contains also the default jvm.lib and i have the same error

Comment: I don't know Embarcadero's IDE.  But for most other IDE's (Visual Studio, for example), you must also specify the name of the lib files, not just the path.  Did you specify `jvm2.lib` in your project as a dependency?

Comment: yes i did this,i said from the begining that it differe to other IDE

Comment: Nowhere did you state that you specified `jvm2.lib` in your project.  You only stated that you have a path, specified the path in your project, and that you placed your lib file there.  Again, that is *not* enough -- you must specify `jvm2.lib` *in your project settings*.  According to this link: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Using_DLLs_in_RAD_Studio_%28C%2B%2B%29 you go to the "Project Manager" and choose "Add".

Comment: yes i did like this,i added the jvm2.lib with the path C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\lib\jvm2.lib and have the same error !!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: i must find how to link EMBARCADERO with JNI to create the JVM